# Consulta multiple en SQ

Tags: sql-server

tengo dos consultas con inner join que pasa que al momento de ejecutar me ejecuta las dos pero en cada parte

### ---------------------------------------------------------------

### Resultado consulta 1

### ---------------------------------------------------------------

### Resultado consulta 2

Por dar un ejemplo, pero yo quiero que salgan en conjunto

### ---------------------------------------------------------------

### Resultado consulta 1 y 2

Mas que no aparezca los resultados de las dos de manera vertical si no que se le agregue mas columnas según venga la consulta 2

por ejemplo

### TABLA 1

### ID           NOMBRE          APELLIDO

1            PEDRO            PEREZ
2            MARIA            PEÑALVER
3            RODOLFO          MARTIN

### TABLA 2

### ID           CURSO

1            A
2            B
3            A

### El resultado que quiero

### ID           NOMBRE          APELLIDO       CURSO

1            PEDRO            PEREZ             A

2            MARIA            PEÑALVER          B

3            RODOLFO          MARTIN            A

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow !!! Para que pueda ayudarte alguien has de ser más específico. Por favor, mira: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y revisa tu pregunta para que quede claro qué es lo que quieres conseguir y cual el obstáculo.

Answer (score 0):

El campo ID es el común en las 2 tablas? esto podría causarte problemas por que si lo tienes autoincrementable, a menos que inserte el mismo numero de cursos como de usuarios al mismo tiempo.

Crea un campo que sea común en las 2 tablas, para que sean PK y FK para poder hacer el JOIN mas efectivo

```
ID NOMBRE APELLIDO IDCURSO
1 PEDRO PEREZ        1
2 MARIA PEÑALVER     2
3 RODOLFO MARTIN     3

TABLA 2
ID CURSO
1    A
2    B
3    A
```

Tu consulta al final quedaría

```
SELECT T1.ID,T1.NOMBRE,T1.APELLIDO, T2.CURSO
FROM TABLA1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLA2 T2 ON T1.IDCURSO = T2.ID
```

Comment: Gracias, pero pero coloque un ejemplo tengo 5 tablas a la cual tengo ya los query que me traen la información pero hay un query que me trae todos los datos del id por ejemplo que tenga el numero '2' y el otro quey todos los datos que tengan el '1' entonces quiero entrelazar esos query, para que me traiga los datos del id '2' como del id '1' en un mismo resultado y de manera horizontal no que se me abajo como fila

Comment: Utiliza el UNION en ese caso! haces tu select principal y haces un unión al segundo select; Ejemplo: SELECT NOMBRE;CURSO FROM TABLA1 UNION SELECT NOMBRE,CURSO FROM TABLA 2, cabe destacar que el mismo numero de columnas que estén en el select principal debe ser el mismo en el segundo

Comment: Hice el union pero no me funciono porque lo agrega a lista osea hacia abajo, no al lado despues de que termine el primer query

Comment: Entonces en tu caso, por el tipo de resultado que necesitas debes usar el PIVOT, te dejo una pagina donde vienen unos ejemplos y la explicación, es un poco complicado usarlos pero es la única manera que conozco de obtener el resultado que necesitas [PIVOT TUTORIAL](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78)